# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule can't get inside matches[1]

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a rewrite rule in Wordpress but it can't return matches[1]:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'stage/shop/([^/]+)/?', "index.php?category_name=$matches[1]", 'top' );
```

But when I try it on pure php it return right thing:

```
preg_match_all('#stage/shop/([^/]+)/?#','stage/shop/audio-and-video-equipment/',$matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

It's my complete code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpst_init_internal' );
function wpst_init_internal()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'stage/shop/([^/]+)/?', "index.php?category_name=$matches[1]", 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpst_query_vars' );
function wpst_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'category_name';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

Is there any problem with my code?

**Update:**

In my query, category_name must return the matches[1] but that's return nothing. It's my dump:

```
  ["category_name"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
```

Comment: add_rewrite_rule() is not returning anything. In wordpress documentation is is not listed that it will return matches. It is used to adding rewriting rule based on url. for that purpose you can use preg_match_all that you have described.

Comment: @siddhesh I konw, I edit and update my question for better explanation.

Comment: have you tried this IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Comment: @siddhesh Yes, I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix my problem:
I enable debug mode in WordPress.
Then I get `Undefined variable: matches` error, it cause of double quote, the rule should be in single quotes.

Comment: Hah, wow, thanks for posting your answer. Double to single quotes fixed it for me as well.